# Unity : Android SDK does not include your Target SDK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build an Android app using Unity and I need to test on different level API.
In order to do that I used Android SDK Manager and downloaded 28, 26 and 24 as you can see on this picture : [image]

**The problem**
Now in Unity when I set the target level API to one of those version I get an error : [image]
[image]

**What I've tried**
The only version which works is when I set level 29 in Unity. I tried every version starting from level 24. I already restarted my computer and nothing changed.

Comment: did you install them in the SDK folder you provided in the External Tools?

Comment: What do you mean ? I used Android Studio by JetBrains Toolbox

Comment: Go to Edit > Preferences > External Tools > SDK go to that folder and open > platforms check if you have the API's there or not.

Comment: It was the missing piece, can you post it as an answer ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the API's installed in the folder you have selected in **External Tools**, open the SDK path and go to **platforms**.

[image]